# Why ocrodjvu's engine not found?

Tags: 14.04, ocr, djvu

I run unsuccessfully in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, trying to have better OCR of a DjVU document

```
ocrodjvu --in-place document.djvu
```

but get `ocrodjvu: error: OCR engine (tesseract) was not found`. 
I found out that this is probably related to some dependency problems. 
Some users have removed some python packages in some cases. 
However, I am not sure.

How can you run ocrodjvu in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, there is no dependency put on `ocrodjvu` about tesseract-ocr. I reported it to upstream [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ocrodjvu/+bug/1594830). Do

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Possibly, you have install also a language.

Systems: Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04